# Type error when trying to fit a VGG like model

Tags: keras, theano, conv-neural-network

When I try to fit the following model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Lambda(vgg_preprocess, input_shape=(3,244,244)),
    Conv2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(axis=1),
    Conv2D(64,3,3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    BatchNormalization(axis=1),
    Conv2D(128,3,3, activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(axis=1),
    Conv2D(128,3,3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    BatchNormalization(axis=1),
    Conv2D(256,3,3, activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(axis=1),
    Conv2D(256,3,3, activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, 4D) (of Variable AbstractConv2d_gradInputs{convdim=2, border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, 256, 56, 56), kshp=(256, 256, 3, 3), filter_dilation=(1, 1)}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, 4D). You can try to manually convert AbstractConv2d_gradInputs{convdim=2, border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), filter_flip=True, imshp=(None, 256, 56, 56), kshp=(256, 256, 3, 3), filter_dilation=(1, 1)}.0 into a TensorType(float64, 4D).
```

This is how I do the fitting:

```
 model.fit_generator(train_batches, train_batches.n, nb_epoch=1, validation_data=test_batches, nb_val_samples=test_batches.n)
```

And here is `vgg_preprocess` function:

```
vgg_mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939]).reshape((3,1,1))

def vgg_preprocess(x):
    x = x - vgg_mean  #Subtract the mean of each channel
    return x[:, ::-1] #Inverse the channel order to suit that of VGG RGB->BGR
```

What does it mean, how to fix it?

Comment: How `vgg_preprocess` looks like?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko It normalizes the inputs and reorder the color channels. I added it to the question

Comment: Could you print out `vgg_mean.dtype`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko it is dtype('float64')

Comment: Try `vgg_mean = np.array(vgg_mean, dtype='float32')`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Would u add this as an answer to the question, it did solve my problem. Thank u

Comment: In 10 minutes, ok?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in a fact that `vgg_mean.dtype = 'float64`, whereas the standard floating point decision in most of DL packages is `float32`.

Setting:

```
vgg_mean = np.array(vgg_mean, dtype='float32')
```

Should fix your problem.